# Is there a way to clean date and time data in r?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am trying to summarize time from 4 am to 12 pm as morning, 12-9 as evening and 9 pm to 4 am as night. I am doing this to make a logistic regression model to know if the arrest would happen or not considering the type of crime and the time of the crime.

I have tried using the lubridate function but because the format is the string I am not able to use the function. And, `as.Date` function is neither of help since some of the strings are having this value: `03/26/2015 06:56:30 PM` while some of the rows have this value: `04-12-15 20:24`. Both the formatting are totally different so not able to use the `as.Date` function.

Apart from the `as.Date` function what we can do is convert all the `04-12-15 20:24` to `03/26/2015 06:56:30 PM` format by doing something like => if you find `-` then replace it with `/` (for the date format).

I don't know how to achieve this goal.

[image: Attached is the image of a part of the data]

Comment: My question is.. Why your `datetime` field has a different format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case_when()` from the `dplyr` library to determine the format of the date and then proceed with the conversion based on the format type. From there we check the 24H time component to determine the time of day based on the bins in the OP.

```
library(dplyr)

chicago15 <- data.frame(Date = c("03/26/2015 06:56:30 PM","04-12-15 20:24",
                             "03/26/2015 06:56:30 AM","04-12-15 21:24",
                             "12/31/2017 03:28:43 AM"))

chicago15 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Date2 = dplyr::case_when(
    grepl('-',Date) ~ as.POSIXct(Date,format = '%m-%d-%y %H:%M'),
    TRUE ~ as.POSIXct(Date,format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
  )) %>%

  dplyr::mutate(Time_of_Day = dplyr::case_when(
    as.numeric(format(Date2,'%H')) >= 21 ~ 'night',
    as.numeric(format(Date2,'%H')) >= 12 ~ 'evening',
    as.numeric(format(Date2,'%H')) >= 4 ~ 'morning',
    TRUE ~ 'night'
  ))

  Date                   Date2               Time_of_Day
1 03/26/2015 06:56:30 PM 2015-03-26 18:56:30     evening
2         04-12-15 20:24 2015-04-12 20:24:00     evening
3 03/26/2015 06:56:30 AM 2015-03-26 06:56:30     morning
4         04-12-15 21:24 2015-04-12 21:24:00       night
5 12/31/2017 03:28:43 AM 2017-12-31 03:28:43       night
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer lacks in quality regarding its **form**. Such input is very likely to be downvoted and closed. Thus: please use the [edit] link to improve your answer. Also, you should note that  *preview* window (together with the help explaining formatting) to improve the quality of your posting.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it lacks in quality regarding the form? I am happy to make improvements if you have specific recommendations.

Comment: Yes, of course, my comment should've been more clear. There is no text explaining your answer, that's all. It was flagged for low-quality.

Comment: That’s a fair point. I have updated my answer with some commentary on the solution.

Comment: Hi Wil, thanks for the code. But this didn't work well because the result dropped the time part of the date and the format didn't change from '-' to '/'. Some of the results are:
 2015-11-24,

    2015-05-19, 
   2015-01-01, 
   2015-06-24, 
   2015-04-09, 
   2015-07-29, 
   2015-08-14

Comment: @ParthParikh I have updated my answer to create the time of day groupings for you. Are you concerned about the '-' in the date format? My new solution converts all of them to the standard `POSIXct()` format used for dates in R. That format can be changed for print purposes, but the underlying data remains the same and can be used to drive your time of data groupings regardless of how it is formatted.

Comment: @Wil Thank you so much for the solution. It worked perfectly fine for me. Again, many thanks.

Comment: @ParthParikh happy to help. If this answer solves your problem, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.